# Swift closures - order of code execution in regards to value assignment

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I would like to know in details the proper order of execution when working on data in a completion handler. I have the following function definition on my Event class:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchEvents(completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> () = { _ in }) -> [Event] {
    let fetch = self.fetchEventRequest()

    var entities: [Event] = []
    context.perform {
        entities = try! fetch.execute()
        completion(entities)
    }
    return entities
}
```

And I call the above function from my view controller as such:

```
events = MyEvents.fetchEvents() { entities in
        if (entities.count == 0) {
            self.events = Event.getEventsFromAPI()
        } 
        print(events.count) - // returns 0 at this point
        self.eventsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Upon calling `self.eventsTableView.reloadData()` my `events` variable is still empty. I would assume that since the completion handler executes after successful execution of the code inside the function, the `events` var would have already been assigned the returned value, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a summary of your function in question:

```
...
context.perform {
    entities = try! fetch.execute()
    completion(entities)
}
return entities
```

Swift sees it like this:

1. Call this `context.perform` function
2. Call `return entities`
3. Process the output of `context.perform` inside the closure

Because of the order, it just returns the value and considers its work done. Your closure will likely complete, assuming it stays in scope, but otherwise nothing comes of it.

The easiest thing would be to change your function from:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchEvents(completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> () = { _ in }) -> [Event]
```

to:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchEvents(completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> () = { _ in })
```

The difference here is the removal of the `[Event]` return.

Then, inside your function remove the `return entities` line.

You now have an asynchronous function, so whatever you use to call it will have to use a closure for the [Event] value.

`self.events = Event.getEventsFromAPI()` becomes something like:

```
Event.getEventsFromAPI() = { [weak self] events in
    self?.events = events
}
```

Comment: yeah that's the "workaround" I was going for initially but I was also second guessing if that is a correct approach so I'm glad to see this validated. Thanks for the explanation